# how to create json array of multiple json object ?

Tags: php, json

am trying to generate a json array with multiple json objects within it. below is my code with output.

```
<?php

    include_once "/db_connect.php";
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $head='0';
    if(empty($head)){

    for($head=1;$head<20;$head++){
    if(!empty($head)){

    $flatp=mysql_query("SELECT co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.flatP,hds.HeadName,co.offer_name,u.shop_name,co.cost FROM createdoffers co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN 
            users u ON u.id=co.user_id INNER JOIN heads hds ON hds.id=ct.Head_id 
            WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id AND co.user_id=u.id ORDER BY co.flatP DESC LIMIT 1");

        if (mysql_num_rows($flatp) >0) {
        $response["createdoffers"] = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($flatp)) {
        $recp = array();

                $recp["HeadName"]= $row["HeadName"];
                $recp["offer_name1"]=$row["offer_name"];
                $recp["shop_name1"]=$row['shop_name'];
                $recp["cost1"]=$row['cost'];

            array_push($response["createdoffers"], $recp);

        }
        $object=array(array_filter((array)$response));  
        $res = json_encode($object);
         echo trim($res,'[]');
        }               

    }

    }
    }
    ?>
```

and this is my output which has different json objects with different json arrays..

{"createdoffers":[{"HeadName":"Automotives","offer_name1":"flat","shop_name1":"coding spider","cost1":"1300.00"}]}

{"createdoffers":[{"HeadName":"Computer and Electroincs","offer_name1":"happy hour","shop_name1":"coding spider","cost1":"17000.00"}]}

{"createdoffers":[{"HeadName":"Food and Dining","offer_name1":"flat","shop_name1":"codingspider","cost1":"100.00"}]}

what i want is to generate all these three json objects into one json array. am unable to find whats wrong in this ..

Comment: `json_decode` the three objects, add them to a new array, and `json_encode` then `return` that.

Comment: hi @mopsyd .. in this code each json object is generated through for loop iteration. now i dont understand how to put each iteration into one object and then put them all into one array.. any sample code with for loop or any link will be helpful. thank u.

Comment: `$result = array();`
`for($head=1;$head<20;$head++){`
`//...do stuff`
`$result[] = $object`
`}`
`return json_encode($result);`

Comment: Take the json_encode out of your loop and push the result into an array instead. After the for loop completes json_encode the resulting array instead.

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i got the answer.. thank u @mopsyd for help.

Comment: this array-->  $response["createdoffers"] = array(); was within ime the for loop so every the loop iterated,this array also iterated. this created individual object each time.

Comment: i just took out this response array out of array and declared it at the top before for loop and it worked fine

Comment: Glad things worked out for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php

    include_once "/db_connect.php";
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
    $head='0';
    $response["createdoffers"] = array();
    if(empty($head)){

    for($head=1;$head<20;$head++){
    if(!empty($head)){

    $flatp=mysql_query("SELECT  co.id,co.user_id,co.cat_id,co.flatP,hds.HeadName,co.offer_name,u.shop_name,co.cost FROM createdoffers co INNER JOIN categories ct ON ct.id=co.cat_id INNER JOIN 
            users u ON u.id=co.user_id INNER JOIN heads hds ON hds.id=ct.Head_id 
            WHERE ct.Head_id='$head' AND ct.id=co.cat_id AND co.user_id=u.id ORDER BY co.flatP DESC LIMIT 1");

        if (mysql_num_rows($flatp) >0) {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($flatp)) {
        $recp = array();

                $recp["HeadName"]= $row["HeadName"];
                $recp["offer_name1"]=$row["offer_name"];
                $recp["shop_name1"]=$row['shop_name'];
                $recp["cost1"]=$row['cost'];

            array_push($response["createdoffers"], $recp);

        }
        $object=array(array_filter((array)$response));  
        $res = json_encode($object);
         echo trim($res,'[]');
        }               

    }

    }
    }
    ?>
```